# Azure web api authentication

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

I would like to secure my Azure WebApi with 3rd party providers (FB, G+... I basically just need a valid email). Was looking at Auth0 and seems like it will do the thing paired with Jwt middleware in web api project, but I was wondering if the same can be done using Azure only.

Azure Web App authentication confused me a bit - it does not seem to give anything to my Asp.Net web app. I still have to configure all the middleware in Startup.cs and the app still works fine if I completely turn authentication off.

I could do the same thing Auth0 does - issue my own Jwt tokens based on access tokens from FB or G+ - but would like to avoid that.

Could you please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple options:

- [App Service Authentication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-app-service-authentication-authorization/)
- [Configure the authentication via middle ware](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services)

#### App Service Authentication

The App Service Authentication does not require any code inside your application because your App Service has a gateway that inspects request for authorization.  Depending on the setting you can either secure the entire site or secure individual resources (by using the `[Authorize]` attribute on the endpoint in MVC/WebAPI).

With the latest release you can control authorization on a site by site basis including manually triggering the sign in  by navigating the user to the `<yoursiteurl>/.auth/login/<provider>`.  By defualt the token store is enabled so you can make a request to `<yoursiteurl>/.auth/me` and get back information from the provider.

#### Middleware Authentication

This is the default way authorization happens in the Single Page ASP.NET Template. The middleware authentication uses OAuth/OpenId to secure the resources.  This option does it at the application layer instead of at the gateway.  If you are using ASP.NET Identity (from the single page project template) the email from the persons log in will automatically be stored in the Users table. The tutorial in the link above gives lots of details on how to get it working.

Make sure you use the `[Authorize]` attribute to trigger the Authorization in either case.

Hope that helps you get started in the right direction.

Comment: It might be that ASA does not work yet with Asp.Net Core - Principal is not passed to the app.

The second option involves token generation which I would like to avoid in my app because token server was removed from Core and recommended way now is using 3rd party IdentityServer.

Comment: I'll mark this as an answer because if not for Asp.Net Core the first option would have obviously worked.